# Bootstrap: Fix the text input position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have label/input fields as `form-inline`. Label text has been wrapped so that form fields can be aligned. But when label is getting wrapped it's corresponding input field is adjusting vertically. How can I fix that?
**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">First Name:</label><input type="text" required/></div>
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Middle Initial:</label><input type="text"  /></div>
            </div>
<div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">How long with current employer</label><input type="text"/></div>
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Middle Initial:</label><input type="text"/></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Last Name:</label><input type="text"/></div>
                <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Social Security Number:</label><input type="text"/></div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col1 .col2 {
    width: 48%;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

    label.pocLabel {
        width: 200px;

    }
    .show-grid [class*="span"] {
        text-align: left;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        min-height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: inline;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you are asking... Would you try and explain further? I made a jsfiddle out of what you posted... http://jsfiddle.net/szRYX/

Comment: I don't get what you wan too.. Please clarify your questions and include a what-you-want section too. Thx

Comment: Added a screenshot. So the label which is getting wrapped its corresponding textbox is not inline. Hope this helps

Comment: `form-inline` should be applied to the form. I suggest you change your markup to a `form-horizontal` with the control-groups divided in two columns. Take a read on [Bootstrap's docs on HTML forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting vertical-align:middle; on the label.